# how to write a small code to grep something that is not passing healthcheck

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

this is the output of a command.

```
kube-system    weave-net-j5mnw                            2/2     Running       0          249d  
kube-system    weave-net-thrlb                            2/2     Running       2          249d    
kube-system    weave-net-tm9ps                            2/2     Running       2          249d    
logging        alert-manager-79fb9f847c-28zk7             1/1     Running       2          2d9h    
logging        fluentd-billing-0                          1/1     Running       0          3d11h
```

I want to grep the 2nd and 3rd column (which is a health-check), and printout if the 3rd column is 0/1 or 0/2  or 1/2. In short , to printout the 2nd and 3rd column if it fails healthchecks.

Please help. New to linux.

Comment: Pipe the output of that command into AWK and extract the needed columns to test. Once that works, you can pipe the output into a log file or whatever. If you want to do everything in one command, save the command in a shell script and then you can run it from your path whenever you need to.

Comment: @DENNY MATHEW: can you show the expected output?

Comment: @User123 - the output should show as Failed.. if 0/1 or 1/2 or 0/2 appears

Answer (score 0):

```
cat out |                          # get the output
tr -s ' ' |                        # squash whitespace
cut -d ' ' -f 2,3 |                # select columns 2 and 3, using space as column seperator
grep -e '0/1' -e '0/2' -e '1/2'    # grep only the lines that include a failure
```

Answer (score 0):

*script.sh* loops through each line of *file.txt*, grabs both digits from **0/2** and compares them.
If they are the same it will print PASSED.
If they are not the same, it will print FAILED.

**file.txt** (added some fails into it)

```
kube-system weave-net-j5mnw 0/2 Running 0 249d
kube-system weave-net-thrlb 2/2 Running 2 249d
kube-system weave-net-tm9ps 2/2 Running 2 249d
logging alert-manager-79fb9f847c-28zk7 1/1 Running 2 2d9h
logging fluentd-billing-0 0/1 Running 0 3d11h
```

**script.sh**

```
while read x; do

    test_result=$(echo "$x" | cut -d ' ' -f3 | cut -d '/' -f1) # gets the first number in 0/1
    test_base=$(echo "$x" | cut -d ' ' -f3 | cut -d '/' -f2) # gets the second number in 0/1

    if [[ "$test_result" == "$test_base" ]]; then
        echo "$x - PASSED"
    else
        echo "$x - FAILED!"
    fi

done <file.txt  # while loop through the file.txt file
```

**result:**

```
kube-system weave-net-j5mnw 0/2 Running 0 249d - FAILED!
kube-system weave-net-thrlb 2/2 Running 2 249d - PASSED
kube-system weave-net-tm9ps 2/2 Running 2 249d - PASSED
logging alert-manager-79fb9f847c-28zk7 1/1 Running 2 2d9h - PASSED
logging fluentd-billing-0 0/1 Running 0 3d11h - FAILED!
```

Comment: test_result=$(echo "$x" | cut -d ' ' -f3 | cut -d '/' -f1) # gets the first number in 0/1

from this .. can you explain the syntax.. how will it pick up exactly the first number, avoiding all the characters before that ? Please explain.

Comment: Cut is doing all the work. The first cut uses ' ', a space as the deliminator and gets the third chunk of text separated by the deliminator. The second cut command uses / as the deliminator.

Comment: Hi Justin,
klgpw is the command to see the status of PODs. the output would look something like :

Answer (score 0):

An awk program which prints column 2 & 3 if column 3 is less than 1:

```
command | awk '$3 < 1 {print $2, $3}'
```

Comment: @user14414078 , 1/1 or 2/2 is not a mathematical calculation.. but a healthcheck.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check below if it works:

`awk '{if ($3 == "0/1" || $3 == "0/2" || $3 == "1/2") print "Failed"; else print $2,"\t",$3;}' file_name`